# Error System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code

Tags: vb.net

I try to get automatic click on a button on a page on my website
I have try multiple things and i can not get out of this exception 
This is My code
Well wen i press the button1 its come an error
I describe below code

```
Public Class Form5
    Dim CheckButton, skip_ad_button As HtmlElement
    Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        WebBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = True
        WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form5_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub



    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        skip_ad_button = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("skip_ad_button")
        CheckButton = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("skip_ad_button")

        If Not skip_ad_button Is Nothing Then
            skip_ad_button.InnerText = "skip_ad_button" 'Replace testID by the ID you want
        End If

        If Not CheckButton Is Nothing Then
            'some code here
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http:\\mediaads.eu/proxy")

    End Sub
End Class
```

This is the error

> System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233067
>   Message=Property is not supported on this type of HtmlElement.
>   Source=System.Windows.Forms
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement.set_InnerText(String value)
>   at WindowsApplication1.Form5.WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(Object sender,
>
> WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) in \Documents\Visual Studio 
>       2012\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form5.vb:line 23

Comment: What is the HTML type of the element `skip_ad_button`? Is it an `input`, a `button`, or something else? Regardless of the answer, it is clear that you cannot set the `InnerText` property of that element - perhaps you need to set an attribute in order to accomplish whatever it is you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: [Turn `option strict` to ON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/5897829)

Comment: Yes its a button id element and i want to automatic press this button

Comment: I have try to set option strict to on but it continue to give me the same error how can i solve it

Comment: See @RB comment.  what if you try `skip_ad_button.setAttribute("value", "skip_ad_button")` versus `skip_ad_button.InnerText = ...`

Comment: Tank you @JimmySmith  Now I Have No More Errors but wen the page is load and my website its come the button its the but there is no automatic click at all

Comment: Glad!  When you say no automatic click, you cannot click the button now or it won't programmatically click it for you?

Comment: Sorry what i mean its it should catch the attribute but nothing happen